# Reduce/deconstruct first n properties of object into a new object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return the first n properties of an object, I don't care what order they "should" be in (numeric, alphabetic etc). I am currently returning these n properties as an array, but having to manage this array downwind is getting annoying.

Example input dataset:

```
{
      "0.00530016": "0.18990380",
      "0.00531201": "0.39754144",
      "0.00531202": "15.93707742",
      "0.00531454": "7.17396155",
      "0.00531512": "0.37666027",
      "0.00533384": "83.98047315",
      "0.00535753": "2.74703930",
      "0.00535997": "1.13950885",
      "0.00536000": "53.12723251",
      "0.00537968": "5.27397661",
      "0.00539234": "3.63687246"
}
```

Returning the first 5 would yield a new object that looks like:

```
{
      "0.00530016": "0.18990380",
      "0.00531201": "0.39754144",
      "0.00531202": "15.93707742",
      "0.00531454": "7.17396155",
      "0.00531512": "0.37666027"
}
```

My current solution of returning these values into an array via this code:

```
foo.property = Object.entries(dataset).slice(0, depth);
```

Yields the following result:

```
[
        [
            "0.00530016",
            "0.18990380"
        ],
        [
            "0.00531201",
            "0.39754144"
        ],
        [
            "0.00531202",
            "15.93707742"
        ],
        [
            "0.00531454",
            "7.17396155"
        ],
        [
            "0.00531512",
            "0.37666027"
        ]
]
```

**So, how can I either mutate that array I already have into the example object, or how can I return that example object in the first place without this array?**

I've tried using reduce on the end of my existing code but I am a bit inexperienced here so I think I am doing something wrong since this needs to be dynamic.

Comment: javascript objects don't have an order

Comment: @marvel308 I know that's what everyone is getting hung up on but I don't care what order it gets returned in, just that it's the first N amount.

Comment: first N in an sorted order ? sorted according to keyName?

Comment: @marvel308 "sorted" according to whatever order they happen to come out in at the time. The order literally doesn't matter, only that there is N amount in a new object. If it helps this object is being constructed from a JSON file. As you can see that dataset is already sorted and always will be.

Comment: @tsujp The term "first" makes no sense when objects have no order. You better ask for "take some N properties out of the object".

Comment: Ah right. Sorry about that. I suppose marvel308's answer solves that problem with his .sort() then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript objects don't have an order, but since you're referring to them in an sorted order you could do

```js
let obj = {
      "0.00530016": "0.18990380",
      "0.00531201": "0.39754144",
      "0.00531202": "15.93707742",
      "0.00531454": "7.17396155",
      "0.00531512": "0.37666027",
      "0.00533384": "83.98047315",
      "0.00535753": "2.74703930",
      "0.00535997": "1.13950885",
      "0.00536000": "53.12723251",
      "0.00537968": "5.27397661",
      "0.00539234": "3.63687246"
}

let result = Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b) => a-b).slice(0, 5).reduce((a, b) => {
    a[b] = obj[b];
    return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

If you don't want the order to matter just remove the sort

Comment: `(+a)-(+b)` is the same as `a-b`

Comment: + operator converts it into a number

Comment: and so does `-`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a loop to copy properties and break out after n properties:

```
function getSomeProperties(obj, N) {
    var res = {};
    var i = 0;
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (i++ >= N) return res;
        res[p] = obj[p];
    }
    return res; // or throw an error that there were less than N properties in obj
}
```

Comment: Not enough <s>jquery</s> reduce! ;)

Comment: @georg Sure one could do it with `keys`+`slice`+`reduce`, but a plain loop is simpler and more efficient :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to return the first n properties of an object, I don't
>   care what order they "should" be in (numeric, alphabetic etc).

If the order doesn't matter (it means you will fetch any 5 properties), then try this

```js
var depth = 5;
var obj = {
      "0.00530016": "0.18990380",
      "0.00531201": "0.39754144",
      "0.00531202": "15.93707742",
      "0.00531454": "7.17396155",
      "0.00531512": "0.37666027",
      "0.00533384": "83.98047315",
      "0.00535753": "2.74703930",
      "0.00535997": "1.13950885",
      "0.00536000": "53.12723251",
      "0.00537968": "5.27397661",
      "0.00539234": "3.63687246"
};
var output={}; 
Object.keys( obj ).slice( 0, depth ).forEach( function( key ){ output[ key ] = obj[ key ] });
console.log( JSON.stringify( output, 0, 4 ) );
```

Comment: That's it. The input dataset is already sorted and always will be. No kind of sorting has to be done on that before N items are returned. So this is this not guaranteed to return 0.00530016, 0.00531201, 0.00531202, 0.00531454, and 0.00531512 then?

Comment: No, because as has been explained object properties aren't in order. You can't sort an object.

Comment: I don't think the order of properties is guaranteed as per spec, so yes it may give a different result next time.

Answer (score 0):

This will `mutate` the original `dataset` using `delete`.

```js
var dataset = {
  "0.00530016": "0.18990380",
  "0.00531201": "0.39754144",
  "0.00531202": "15.93707742",
  "0.00531454": "7.17396155",
  "0.00531512": "0.37666027",
  "0.00533384": "83.98047315",
  "0.00535753": "2.74703930",
  "0.00535997": "1.13950885",
  "0.00536000": "53.12723251",
  "0.00537968": "5.27397661",
  "0.00539234": "3.63687246"
};

function getNObjects(dataset, depth) {
  var i = 0;
  for (var key in dataset) {
    if (i >= depth) {
      delete dataset[key];
    }
    i++;
  }
  return dataset;
}


console.log(getNObjects(dataset, 5));
```